# Folder name has changed while copied indices from AWS ElasticSearch to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am following below link for "Use Amazon S3 to Store a Single Amazon Elasticsearch Service Index"
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-amazon-s3-to-store-a-single-amazon-elasticsearch-service-index/

I am successfully able to upload the indices from AWS Elasticseach to S3 bucket, but also noticed that folder name has changed on S3 bucket.

Folder name on ElasticSearch: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P2Xy.png)

Folder name on S3 bucket: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh6dC.png)

Answer (score 0):

in s3 bucket back up will be stored in UUID not as the index name as in aws elasticsearch. if want to know which UUID is related with index name use below command
curl -X GET "https://search-test-sfjajbfjsbf.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v&health=yellow"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html